# How to port Selenium Firefox (IDE) Tests to other Browsers? (windows)

Tags: windows, testing, browser, selenium, firefox-addon

I have written quite a few testcases with the selenium IDE plugin on firefox.

I now want to run these tests on other browsers. As far as I know there are no similar plugins so I propably have to use the selenium-driver. My quesiton now is: how should I export and write these testcases? I'm running Windows, otherwise I would have exported to ruby.

Comment: official site has good docs http://seleniumhq.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way (and as far as my knowledge, the only way) is to export the Selenium Testcases in the programming language of your choice. Selenium supports - *Java, C#, Python, Ruby, PHP and Perl*.

Once you export the test cases you can apply your own logic (it's a limitless world atleast we want to believe so) and use **drivers** for other browsers like IE, Chrome, Opera, even Android etc to run the test in any browser of your choice. There is even a driver to run your test in a headless manner(HTMLUnit).

You can explore thousands of tutorials in this matter and can get started in minutes.

P.S: People might want to edit this answer for better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The following method can be used to have your test launch other browsers:

```
    public WebDriver getDriver(String driverName)
{

    WebDriver driver = null;  

    if( driverName == "firefox")
    {
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if( driverName == "chrome")
    {
       File chromeFile = new File("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeFile.getAbsolutePath());
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if( driverName == "ie")
    {
       File ieFile = new File("C:/webdrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieFile.getAbsolutePath());
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    return driver;
}
```

If you are using TestNG you can define your test method like so:

```
@Test
public void verifyElements_FF()
{
    verifyElements("firefox");
}
```

For launching Chrom and IE you will need to download the drivers and then place them where your test can reach them and change the path to those drivers in the method above.

Comment: Thanks for your piece of Java code. I created some tests using Firefox Selenium IDE, how can i play my tests using your code ?